# Farsi Alphabet Tips

Tags: persian

I do not understand how I can learn the Farsi (Persian) alphabet. I try to look at it in order and memorize but it just doesn't stick. Are there any websites that anybody knows about that can help, or other techniques that don't involve rote m

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please check our [Help Center](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting. Pure language learning tips questions are off topic on this site. Also, asking for lists is not advised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tip: try to write in your own language with the Persian alphabet, that will let you remember it and allow you to acquire faster writing skills. I always did it with all the writing systems I learned, it always works.